# DataTable Row count always returning 1

Tags: c#, ms-access, datatable

I am trying to get the total number of rows of a table using a data adapter but my row count always returns 1. When i use the reader, I get the accurate number. I would like to use a dataAdapter.

Here is my code:

```
public double GetRowNumber()
    {
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(someConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
       String cmdString = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM " + "[" + Table +"]" 

            OleDbDataAdapter db = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdString, dbConn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            db.Fill(dt);
            return dt.Rows.Count;

        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function will always return 1 because

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM "
```

statement will fill your datatable with 1 record, the number of count.

If you want the row count use

```
   con.Open();
   String cmdString = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM " + "[" + Table +"]" 
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
   cmd.Text = cmdString ;
   cmd.Connection = con;
   int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

more quick and light for what you want. You do not have to use an object such datatable.

Comment: Good answer, but with a simple example will be better

Comment: OK, but is Convert.ToInt32 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because your query is returning only one row. If you  run sql server manager and execue your query.

The result will be like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The table does have only one row. It contains a single cell, with the amount of rows in the database for the table in the query. That is, the result of your query is a one row, one column set.

Instead of dt.Rows.Count, you could return `dt.Rows[0][0];`, but that's overkill. But in a case like this, I think using [ExecuteScalar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalar.aspx) is the best practice (ninja'ed from kostas so kudos and upvotes to him).